# Customize the validator with the session without injection

Tags: php, session, constraints, symfony

My question is: How to pass the session in my class `ContainsExampleValidator` without using dependency injection.

What I would like is to give annotation in an argument over a field when I use my custom validation.

---

Here is my code :

In services.yml :

```
app.validator_constraints.contains_example_validator:
    class: AppBundle\Validator\Constraints\ContainsExampleValidator
    arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager', '@session']
    tags:
        - { name: validator.constraint_validator }
```

In Constraint Class :

```
namespace AppBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;

/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class ContainsExample extends Constraint
{

    public $message = 'Customize my default message';

    public function validatedBy()
    {
        return get_class($this).'Validator';
    }
}
```

In my ContainsExampleValidator :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Validator\Constraints;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintValidator;

class ContainsExampleValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    /**
     * @var EntityManager
     */
    protected $em;


    protected $session;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager, Session $session)
    {
        $this->em = $entityManager;
        $this->session = $session;
    }
}
```

In my entity :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use AppBundle\Validator\Constraints\ContainsExample;

class Entity
{
/**
 * @ContainsExample(message="customize my message")
 */
protected $myfield;
```

---

**Can you give an argument in the session annotation validation?**

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `JMSDiExtraBundle`: https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSDiExtraBundle. It contains a lot of goodies for the dev's life.

What you are looking for is probably this: http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSDiExtraBundle/master/annotations#inject